# Access Denied trying to gather WMI information using C# ASP.NET but works in powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi

I am trying to query hardware data of computers on my local domain using **WMI** in a **C# ASP.NET Application** running on a server using **IIS**.

After successfully opening a cim session using the `New-CimSession` cmdlet and querying WMI data in powershell I tried to acomplish the same thing using `CimSession.Create` in C#.

However when trying to query the same data using C# I receive an `Access Denied` error with code `0x80070005`.
According to the microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-troubleshooting) this is caused by DCOM.

So far I have been unable to come up with a different solution and I find it weird that essentially the same attempt works fine when using powershell.

Some general information:

- My account has local administrator permissions on the remote machine (as required when using a cim session to execute wmi queries)
- I already looked into firewall and connectivity issues and tried running my application outside of **IIS**

Successful attempt in powershell:

```
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName "PC-HOSTNAME" -Credential (Get-Credential)
Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CimSession -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
```

Code example trying to use the **same credentials** from the windows user logged in on the server running the application without passing explicit authentication parameters:

```cs
CimSession session = CimSession.Create("PC-HOSTNAME");
// The next line results in the error
var response = session.QueryInstances(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
```

This should work as is but to make sure I also tried passing explicit authentication parameters which also results in the same error:

```cs
DComSessionOptions dComOptions = new DComSessionOptions();
dComOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationType.Impersonate;

//Build secure string from plain text for representation
var somePasswordString = "password"
var password = new SecureString();
somePasswordString.ToList().ForEach(x => password.AppendChar(x));

dComOptions.AddDestinationCredentials(new CimCredential(PasswordAuthenticationMechanism.Default, "mydomain.local", "myusername", password));
        
CimSession session = CimSession.Create("PC-HOSTNAME");
// The next line results in the error
var response = session.QueryInstances(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
```

I have seen many different approaches on WMI in C# but using `CimSession` with the `QueryInstances` method seemed to be the most straight forward for my use case. Nonetheless all other code examples I found resulted in the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

#### Update

As pointed out by [@IanKemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70345/ian-kemp) I understand that it's bad practice to run operations requiring administrator permissions in a web application. However I am just trying to figure out how to run a basic WMI query in C# and what issues could lead to me getting the described `Access Denied` error whereas it works perfectly fine using powershell.

#### Update V2

I have found an interesting answer on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/a/1105113

> If you are trying to access WMI there are two protocols available: DCOM and WinRM. Which protocol you are using will depend on the tools or API being used. For example, when you are using PowerShell, the 'older' Get-WmiObject cmdlet uses DCOM, whereas the 'newer' Get-CimInstance cmdlet uses WinRM.

This could explain why powershell behaves differently in my case but I still had no luck finding a solution to get it to work in C#

Comment: Web sites shouldn't be performing operations that require them to have administrator access on the machines they're running on; this is basic security practice. Instead you need to create a Windows service of some sort that runs as Administrator, executes the WMI queries you require, and publishes them somewhere (data store, message bus, etc.). Then your website consumes that data.

Comment: @IanKemp thanks for your comment! My application is built around an existing codebase with a web interface. I will think about splitting it up in the future! But nevertheless I am unable to successfully connect to a client using my C# code provided above even when trying the code snippets in a basic console application outside of iis.

Comment: @IanKemp as a quick follow up to your comment: Is a simple web api still considered bad practice if the backend then schedules the WMI scans using something like Hangfire? I need tight interaction and configurability on the scans and how they are scheduled and it's not the only thing the application will be doing on the backend side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error I have found a solution to my problem.

As mentioned in my "Update V2" this post lead to my solution: https://serverfault.com/a/1105113

Two things that resolved my problem:

1. I granted my user 'Remote Enable' permissions under WMI control as mentioned in the post on serverfault
2. In development I have to run Visual Studio as Administrator (don't know why but this resolved any Access Denied issues I encountered earlier even though I authenticated as administrator in code)

Edit: I posted a new post about using wmi without admin permissions [Running wmi queries as a non-admin user on a remote machine using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78237150/running-wmi-queries-as-a-non-admin-user-on-a-remote-machine-using-c-sharp)